# From Free to In-App Purchase swift / iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have released an app to App Store and few updates to it as well. Currently the app is free. My plan is that it will be free for download, but with limited use. By in-app-purchase user could unlock the unlimited version.

So I want that the existing users can have the app still for free, but the new users would have the limited usage if they have not bought the unlimited version via IAP. So how should I approach this scenario? I read some articles about fetching the app store receipt and reading the original_app_version, but got a bit lost here. Is that the only path to go?

Cheers,
JM

Answer (score 0):

The right solution would be to rely on the original app version. This way there is no action from your users needed (as every user would expect) and no need for you to explain to them why they now have to buy something, that's free. Also what about users who have currently not installed your app or do not use it during your switching phase?

Relying on the original app version is much more future proof and more comfortable for you and your users. Additionally, you can skip the switching phase and start directly making money on new users.

Since you want to integrate an in-app purchase you have to learn how to work with the receipt anyway. So why not do it right from the beginning.

**How do I access the receipt and get the original app version?**

My recommendation for accessing the receipt is [TPInAppReceipt](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt). It is easy to integrate and gets updates on a regular base. In your component to validate the receipt and purchases you only need to do:

```swift
do {
  /// Initialize receipt
  let receipt = try InAppReceipt.localReceipt() 
  let originalAppVersion = receipt.originalAppVersion
  if Float(originalAppVersion) < YOUR_LATEST_FREE_VERSION {
    // unlock all features
  }
  
} catch {
  // handle no receipt error
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is true. There are some cons in the 1st solution candidate as you mentioned. Thank you for the recommendation for accessing the receipt. I'll check that one as well. So far I have tried to avoid using any third party code...

Comment: By the way, was it so that the build number is actually compared and not the actual app version? Currently my build numbers are not unique, but since I have now all the released versions marked as build '1' -> I could later start to increase it on every release.

Comment: The *orignalAppVersion* field in the receipt corresponds to the value of CFBundleVersion (in iOS) or CFBundleShortVersionString (in macOS) in the Info.plist file when the purchase was originally made. You can set this to whatever you want. We use out commits count

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is setup the in-app purchase now, but make it free.  That would allow existing users to purchase the app for free.  Then, at some point in the future, change the price to whatever you want and the users who already purchased it for free can just restore the purchase later on if they ever have to, without having to pay for it.

Comment: Nice! That actually would be a very simple solution! Thank you :)

Comment: @jmaggis No problem, now that you brought up this topic, I'm thinking of doing something similar with one of my own apps, to get some more downloads and momentum going with it.