# Determine If User Purchase While Installing

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

There are four types of In-App Purchase

Consumable
Non‑Consumable
Auto‑Renewable Subscriptions
Non‑Renewing Subscriptions

However, there is another type of purchase. Like while in-app store you might say $3.99. When you install this app, simultaneously you have to pay for this app.

**What is the name of such purchases.?**

**From code level how could I find If the purchases or not?**

Use case: I made my app free and then paid then again free. Now I want to implement Add in my app. I want those paid users do not to show the Advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/business-models/) is a list of possible business models. What you are describing is the **paid** model: users have to pay upfront to use your app. In that case, you know, every user using your app paid already, because otherwise, Apple hadn't allowed the download.

When you change your business model from there to freemium or with ads, then the answer is the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938982/from-free-to-in-app-purchase-swift-ios-app/65950927#65950927): check the original app version in the receipt and unlock feature(s) or remove ads when the user bought your app before you changed your business model.

Comment: "In that case, you know, every user using your app paid already" This is not true in case of mine. Like in the same version I Made it Purchase option then made it free from the iTunesConnect. In this case some users are paid and some users are free. In next release, I will advertisement. And want to off those user who already paid for my app.

Comment: Wasn't aware you already made the app free. As far as I know, no receipt field indicates that a user paid money and since changing the price doesn't require you to upload a new binary, the only way (I see) is to disable ads based on the `orginalPurchaseDate` field in the receipt. This isn't super accurate so I would add one day to the date you made your app free to ensure all users who bought your app on the switch-date get the app without ads. This way there are potentially users who got the app for free and can use it without ads, but this is better than users gets ads although they paid.