# Swift InAppPurchases - give previous customers a free lifetime subscription

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, free, subscription

So my App was released to the AppStore some months ago and was free to download. I gained like 2k Users. Now I am implementing an auto renewable Subscription model, so future users can use the demo app for free and subscribe to get the full content.

How ever I want to thank my Users "from day one" by giving them free access to all content without paying the subscription.

Is there a "given way" how to implement this because it seems like a common scenario. If not, does someone with IAP experience has a smart workaround how to handle/implement it?

Thanks guys :D

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In my eyes, the best way is to check the receipt field `originalAppVersion` to determine if a user can use your app for free. See here for a detailed answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950927/1128713.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Paul didnt work for me. Neither did any other solutions.
But i managed to find a solution.

In case you use CoreData as database within your app, you can use the solution i found out for my app.

**The idea:**

*If someone downloads the app from the appstore, he will receive the latest database version in your app.*

*If someone updates your app, coredata will perform a migration. And this migration updates from bottom to top trough your database versions.*

Through this behavior we have the opportunity to dinstinct the two cases.

**Solution:** We create two new database versions. One will only be updated by the former users. We will set a flag here. The new Users will never get in touch with that.

The **first new one** will create a new attribut field in any entity (e.g. User) e.g. isFormerUser as a Bool. You can set it per default on true.

Now we create a **second new one** (the latest one). Trough a Core Data mapper it will take the $source attributes if it migrates.
So by that case, all FormerUser were set on True and will keep that attribute.
Here will the default be False, so if $source didnt exist, set it on false (new Users).

This solution is nice because it gets set once by that migration/update and **you dont have to carry hardcoded stuff in your app.** Now just create a load/get Function from CoreData for that attribute and set a variable to use in an if-statement.